# How to get the total actual number of inodes for file system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

In the Linux terminal I can do `df -i` to show how the inodes are allocated. That is **explicitly not** what I need.

##### What is the terminal command needed to reveal how many inodes are available to the file system?

**To clarify**: I explicitly do not care about the "theoretical limit" copy-paste "answer" on literally dozens of pages I have searched through today.

`dumpe2fs` result:

```
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Usage: dumpe2fs [-bfhixV] [-o superblock=<num>] [-o blocksize=<num>] device
```

Comment: What's the theoretical limit copy paste answer, from dumpe2fs?

Comment: In other words: please clarify your clarification, it's the most unclear fragment of the question.

Comment: Inodes have a set number correct? Just like a hard drive has a set amount of space, GB or TB. I simply need to determine what the file system's total inode count is.

Comment: What about `df -i` do you believe is "theoretical" and what filesystem type are we talking about? you are not entirely correct in assuming that all volumes of a given size will end up with the same max number of allocate-able inodes, as  they vary in data size.  some filesystem types have a fixed number of inodes possible, whereas many others use a dynamic data structure that doesn't have a fixed limit. in those cases inode max count will be based on the size of the disk and the size of the inodes on it. so the answer you want to find may not be so cut and dried as you think it should be.

Comment: why do you care about that? many modern filesystems just allocate more inodes as needed

Comment: Total inode count is a simple single value on a system with one volume. 4 comments and 34 views and no one can answer a simple question? I don't question people's motives when they buy food or fill up their gas tank.

Comment: "no one can answer a simple question?" – How do you know it's simple? You too cannot answer it, but at least you know what you mean (I sincerely hope). I bet some users know some answer(s), but nobody posts it because *maybe* it is *the* '"theoretical limit" copy-paste "answer"' from 'literally dozens of pages'. We still don't know what this answer is and why it doesn't fit your needs, so how can we exclude it? Besides, [one should only ask practical questions](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). What is the practical problem? Beware of [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).